# I am not able to update wordpress url and site url on AWS EC2

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services

I installed #Wordpress_by_Bitnami in an instance of #AWS_EC2. After installation I wanted to change my wordpress url and site url; however, the options are disabled. How am I able to change these?

Also I need to change the admin email address. I put the email address in, but they didn't send me any OTP to confirm the email.

**I have launched many EC2 instances, installed wordpress, and changed the email many times in the settings, but the problem is same. Is there any setting related to modifying an email or site url when I launch the #Wordpress_by_Bitnami?
   [Here's the screenshot!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rxpze.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can change your Wordpress Site URL and Home URL by using different methods:

**Method_1:** By accessing your WordPress database through PhpMyAdmin or CLI:

a. Search for table: wp_options.

b. Locate the 'siteurl' and 'home' rows.

c. Change the 'option_values' as per requirement.

**Method_2:** Accessing site using FTP or SSH:

a. Edit the file 'wp-config.php'.

b. Add the following lines

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

**To change the Email id:**

a. Access your domain: https://SERVER_IP/wp-admin/

b. Go to the General Setting under the Setting tab.

c. Edit the Email address.

d. Save the changes.

```
Settings >> General Settings >> Email Address >> Save Changes
```